# How to update "bundleUrl" in shell-app-manifest.json?

Tags: ios, react-native, expo

I just upgraded my Expo Detached React Native App from SDK 35 to 38.

I've been able to update all 35.0.0's to 38.0.0's either manually or via npm install, pod install etc...

Besides my `"bundleUrl"` in **shell-app-manifest.json**

How can I update this couldfront.net URL?

Comment: By updating, do you mean completely changing this cloudfront.net url with a very different and custom url? Possibly to the one that you are hosting somewhere else?

Comment: Yes, to clarify I believe I need to generate an entirely new custom url for my project. I've attempted to "update" my current URL by just changing the 35.0.0 to 38.0.0 toward the end of the URL, but then when I npm start and run in Xcode I am getting seeing 'ExpoFatalError', reason: ... AccessDenied

Comment: I see, did you try to run" expo publish" ?

Comment: I had tried so many fixes I just assumed I'd already ran 'expo publish'. I had not! I just ran it and it successfully fixed this error. Thank you!

Comment: Confirmed! @Nostromo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run

```
expo publish
```

to generate a new bundle url